# jqGrid not being populated with JSON data from Java Servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets, jqgrid

Hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

I have already browsed the many other posts relating to jqGrid & json not populating the jqGrid table (some of the links):

[jqGrid - Table not being populated by data from json request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232133/jqgrid-table-not-being-populated-by-data-from-json-request)

[jgGrid not displaying json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164347/jggrid-not-displaying-json-data)

[JSON and jqGrid. What is "userdata"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128837/json-and-jqgrid-what-is-userdata)

[jqGrid with JSON data renders table as empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259435/jqgrid-with-json-data-renders-table-as-empty)

[jqGrid not displaying JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682240/jqgrid-not-displaying-json-data)

but could not find an answer to my problem.

Basically what I am trying to do is read a list of events from a log file (with date and time info) and display in the jqGrid.

This is my setup:

[1] My Servlet snippet

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest aRequest,
            HttpServletResponse aResponse, Hashtable aQueryData,
            LocaleData aLocale) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("doGet(): Received Request: " + aRequest.getServletPath());

        // jqGrid expects the JSON data in a predefined format:
        //      { 
        //            "total": "xxx", 
        //            "page": "yyy", 
        //            "records": "zzz",
        //            "rows" : [
        //              {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
        //              {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
        //                ...
        //            ]
        //      }


        // Calling getLogEntries() method populates logEntries & logEntriesCnt.
        // logEntries contains the "rows" data as specified above.
            // For now I am testing with 10 rows of data.
        getLogEntries(aLocale);

        JSONObject jqGridData = new JSONObject();
        jqGridData.put("total", "1");
        jqGridData.put("page", "1");
        jqGridData.put("records", String.valueOf(logEntriesCnt-1));
        jqGridData.put("rows", logEntries);

        System.out.println("\n\n# Event Log Entries (" + new Date() + "):" + (logEntriesCnt-1));
        System.out.println("jqGrid JSON: \n" + jqGridData.toJSONString());

        aRequest.setAttribute("userdata", jqGridData.toJSONString());

        aRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/eventlogtest.jsp").forward(aRequest, aResponse);
    }
```

The output on the console (I validated it via jsonlint):

```
# Event Log Entries (Fri Dec 09 11:02:25 GMT 2011):10
jqGrid JSON: 
{"total":"1","page":"1","records":"10","rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["09\/12\/11","11:01:52","Communication Established"]},{"id":"2","cell":["09\/12\/11","11:01:52","Monitoring Started"]},{"id":"3","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:50:55","Communication Established"]},{"id":"4","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:50:55","Monitoring Started"]},{"id":"5","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:36:57","Communication Established"]},{"id":"6","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:36:57","Monitoring Started"]},{"id":"7","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:30:58","Communication Established"]},{"id":"8","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:30:58","Monitoring Started"]},{"id":"9","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:21:58","Communication Established"]},{"id":"10","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:21:58","Monitoring Started"]}]}
```

[2] My JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json">

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/ui.jqgrid.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/eventlog.min.js"></script>  

  <title>jqGrid Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>jqGrid Test</h1>

    <form id="formpageform" action="/eventlog" name="eventlogviewerform" method="post">

        <div id="logEntries">
            userdata = ${userdata}
        </div>

        <br/>
        <br/>

        <table id="tableGrid"></table>
        <div id="tablePager"></div>

        <br/>
        <br/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I output the userdata to the screen and again validated the json is correct. Firebug does not have any errors. Here is a link to the screen-shot that I see when page is rendered:
http://tinypic.com/r/acrgus/5

Firebug Console - Parameters:

```
_search false
nd  1323429509833
page    1
rows    10
sidx    dateentry
sord    asc
```

Firebug Console - Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json">

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/ui.jqgrid.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/eventlog.min.js"></script>  

  <title>jqGrid Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>jqGrid Test</h1>

    <form id="formpageform" action="/eventlog" name="eventlogviewerform" method="post">

        <div id="logEntries">
            userdata = {"total":"1","page":"1","records":"10","rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["09\/12\/11","11:18:13","Communication Established"]},{"id":"2","cell":["09\/12\/11","11:18:13","Monitoring Started"]},{"id":"3","cell":["09\/12\/11","11:01:52","Communication Established"]},{"id":"4","cell":["09\/12\/11","11:01:52","Monitoring Started"]},{"id":"5","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:50:55","Communication Established"]},{"id":"6","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:50:55","Monitoring Started"]},{"id":"7","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:36:57","Communication Established"]},{"id":"8","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:36:57","Monitoring Started"]},{"id":"9","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:30:58","Communication Established"]},{"id":"10","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:30:58","Monitoring Started"]}]}
        </div>

        <br/>
        <br/>

        <table id="tableGrid"></table>
        <div id="tablePager"></div>

        <br/>
        <br/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Firebug Console - HTML:

```
jqGrid Test
userdata = {"total":"1","page":"1","records":"10","rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["09\/12\/11","11:18:13","Communication Established"]},{"id":"2","cell":["09\/12\/11","11:18:13","Monitoring Started"]},{"id":"3","cell":["09\/12\/11","11:01:52","Communication Established"]},{"id":"4","cell":["09\/12\/11","11:01:52","Monitoring Started"]},{"id":"5","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:50:55","Communication Established"]},{"id":"6","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:50:55","Monitoring Started"]},{"id":"7","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:36:57","Communication Established"]},{"id":"8","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:36:57","Monitoring Started"]},{"id":"9","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:30:58","Communication Established"]},{"id":"10","cell":["09\/12\/11","10:30:58","Monitoring Started"]}]}
```

[3] My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Test Data: All entries double quoted
    var userdatatest1 = 
        {
            "total":"1",
            "page":"1",
            "records":"10",
            "rows":[
            {"id":"1","cell":["08\/12\/11","21:09:19","Communication Established"]},
            {"id":"2","cell":["08\/12\/11","21:09:19","Monitoring Started"]},
            {"id":"3","cell":["08\/12\/11","21:02:47","Communication Established"]},
            {"id":"4","cell":["08\/12\/11","21:02:47","Monitoring Started"]},
            {"id":"5","cell":["08\/12\/11","20:51:40","Communication Established"]},
            {"id":"6","cell":["08\/12\/11","20:51:40","Monitoring Started"]},
            {"id":"7","cell":["08\/12\/11","20:33:24","Communication Established"]},
            {"id":"8","cell":["08\/12\/11","20:33:24","Monitoring Started"]},
            {"id":"9","cell":["08\/12\/11","20:23:06","Communication Established"]},
            {"id":"10","cell":["08\/12\/11","20:23:06","Monitoring Started"]}]
        };


    // jqGrid Options: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options
    // Pager Options: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager
    $("#tableGrid").jqGrid({
        url:'/eventlogjqgrid',
        datatype:'jsonstring',
        //datastr: userdatatest1,
        colNames:['Date', 'Time', 'Event'],
        colModel:[ 
                {name:'dateentry',index:'dateentry',width:150,align:"left",sortable:false,editable:false}, 
                {name:'timeentry',index:'timeentry',width:150,align:"left",sortable:false,editable:false} ,
                {name:'evententry',index:'evententry',width:400,align:"left",sortable:false,editable:false}
        ],
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        sortname:'dateentry',
        sortorder:'asc',
        pager: jQuery('#tablePager'),
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Event Log'
    }); 

    jQuery("#tableGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#tablePager', {edit:false, add:false, del:false, search:false, refresh:false});

});
```

As you can see from my Javascript. I have test json data that corresponds to the json being sent from server. The test data has no problem being rendered (see screen-shot): 
http://tinypic.com/r/15s7dyx/5

I don't really mind about being able to page the data in the table. I just want to be able display the data and update it every 5 mins. I will do the updates once I get the basic data to display.

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the data which need be used to fill the grid directly on the HTML page you should not use

```
<div id="logEntries">
    userdata = ${userdata}
</div>
```

inside of the HTML body. The data

```
<div id="logEntries">
    userdata = {"total":"1","page":"1",...}
</div>
```

can't be good read by your JavaScript code. Instead of that you can include in the head of the page something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mygriddata = {"total":"1","page":"1",...};
</script>
```

In the case the **global** variable will be set (`window.mygriddata`) and can be used by other JavaScript code placed below in the head. By the way the assignment above is *initializing*. The JSON data are *string* like the following:

```
var mygriddata = '{"total":"1","page":"1",...}';
```

The statement `var mygriddata = {"total":"1","page":"1",...}` defines directly object and not a string. So you can just follow the JavaScript syntax and cab rewrite the code as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mygriddata = {
        total: "1",
        page: "1"//, ...
    };
</script>
```

Now you will be able to use `datatype:'jsonstring'` and `datastr: mygriddata` to fill the grid. The value of `datastr` can be either string or object. If you want use JSON instead of object initialization you code should be modified to include `'` over `${userdata}`:

```
<div id="logEntries">
    userdata = '${userdata}'
</div>
```

If you want to use `datatype:'json'` and get the JSON data from servlet per Ajax, the server code should not write the correct body of the server response `HttpServletResponse` but additionally at least set the `Content-Type` of the response header to `application/json`:

```
aResponse.setContentType("application/json");
```

I don't use Java, so I can't help you in the server code more.

Comment: Hi @Oleg - many thanks for your quick response. Just a few comments in relation to your response. I only included the following in the JSP <div id="logEntries">
    userdata = ${userdata}
</div>
to make sure

Comment: @adrnola: OK, the meaning of `<div id="logEntries"> userdata = ${userdata} </div>` was just unclear for me. In any way during the usage of Firebug you should not only look at the body, but in the HTTP headers also. Especially 'Content-Type' is very important. I recommend you additionally include `loadError` handle in the grid to see possible errors. Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935) for details.